# Why are I/O bound instructions not used as part of a hashing algorithm to thwart ASICs

Tags: mining, asic-mining, asic-development

Is there a reason why I/O bound instructions are not used in the logic for hashing done by miners?

For example, there could be specialised nodes that act as middlemen,  whose sole role would be to dispatch/provide verifiable (timestamped?) pseudo random numbers from authenticated nodes. The provided pseudo random numbers would then be used as part of the hashing algorithm

The bottleneck this will create, will negate any superior speed advantage that ASICs etc. have.

Has this being tried before, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

"Specialized nodes that act as middlemen" defeats the entire purpose of PoW, which is decentralization.

Comment: Ok, with the benefit of hindsight, I could have phrased "Specialized nodes that act as middlemen" better. The concept of different types of actors distributed accross the network, is not a new one. For example, If my understanding is correct, there are already "regular" nodes, as well as miners. Why can't there be another distributed actor in the network whose sole role would be to generate a PRN; there could be some voting/consensus mechanism to choose which generated PRN is selected.

Comment: Uh huh. And what voting consensus mechanism should be used to select this PRNG? Maybe Proof of Work?